# Not able to disable jQuery Modal dialog caching

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, caching, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on MVC4 development where I am using modal dialog to edit the record. I am using ajaxform to submit the updated values to controller. So far the functionality is working fine.  But I am facing a problem with caching which I have been trying to solve but no success. 
The record on main page is being displayed in various tabs and each tab has an edit option. On click of edit I am loading respective partial view on modal dialog. After I launch modal dialog and click cancel change the tab and again click edit the dialog will correctly load the respective partial view for edit. But if I click edit launch modal dialog and update the values then again load the modal popup from another tab, it shows me the edit view of previous tab and not the one I want to edit. I have debugged the code but it does not seem to be the code issue. I have tried to disable by cache: false at modal dialog and application level but nothing works! I am adding a snippet of my modal launch jQuery and modal dialog form code.

```
   $(".model-edit").click(function () {
        var viewid = $(this).attr("id");
        var key = $("#KeyField").val();
        var functionurl = '@Url.Action("ShowEditModel")';

        if (key != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: functionurl,
                cache: false,
                context: this,
                data: { key: key, viewid: viewid },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#model-editor').html(data);
                    $('#model-editor').dialog({ modal: true,
                        width: 'auto', resizable: false, autoOpen: false,
                        closeOnEscape: true, position: 'middle'

                    });
                    myModal = $('#model-editor').dialog('open');
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EditForm");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Modal dialog view.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateRecord",null,null,new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "SelectedRecord", OnSuccess = "closeModal();" }, new { id = "EditForm" } ) )
{

    <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="left" width="950px">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">
            <input type="hidden" value=@Model.CurrentStep id="CurrentStep" name="CurrentStep"/>
        </td>
       </tr>     
      <tr>
        <td  align="center">
         @for (int i = 0; i < ((string[])Model.StepView).Count(); i++)
         {
             if (i == (int)Model.CurrentStep)
             {
              <h2 class="StepTitle">@((string)Model.StepTitle[i])</h2>
             <div class="wizard-step" id=@i style="height:auto;position:relative;display:inherit">
               @Html.Partial((string)Model.StepView[i])
             </div>
             }
             else
             {
              <div class="wizard-step" style="height:auto;position:relative;">
               @Html.Partial((string)Model.StepView[i])
              </div>
             }
         }
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td align="center">
         <div id="buttons" class="actionBar">
           <input type="button" class="button" id="CancelButton" value="Cancel" onclick="closeModal();" />
           <input type="submit" class="button" id="SaveButton" value="Update" style="float:left"/>
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

 <script type="text/javascript">

      function closeModal() {
         $(myModal).dialog('close');

     }

 </script>
}
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue because it works perfect when I click cancel or use X button to close modal dialog. But not when I submit form and close using same JavaScript `closeModal()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the mistake. I just made below change

```
                $('#model-editor').dialog({ modal: true,
                    width: 'auto', resizable: false, autoOpen: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true, position: 'middle'

                });

                 $('#model-editor').html(data); <<= Moved this line after modal initialization
                  myModal = $('#model-editor').dialog('open'); 
                 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EditForm");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
dialog('destroy') instead dialog('close')
```